# How can i set the absolute position of a view in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

I'm using gridlayout for list all object.

I set my textview Height and Width, Like that

```
textView = new TextView(this);
param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.height = 350;
param.width =  350;
```

No problem here, if textView object was settext larger than 350px. My Gridlayout is deteriorated like this pic;

[image]

My Function is here, i have two function for create table. first function set ROW tables, Second function set Column tables.

***Row code and colomn code is here: this code in for loop***

```
 textView = new TextView(this);
                param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                param.height = 350;
                param.width =  350;
                param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
                param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(Integer.parseInt(data.get(j).get("Sequence")));
                textView.setText(data.get(j).get("Label"));
                textView.setLayoutParams(param);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textView.setTextSize(14);
                textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle));
                gridLayout.addView(textView);
                param.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

I want to do change textview position to absolute.

Comment: set your textView `maxlines = 1`

Comment: im tried not working.